# Get values for each row element in a csv from the values of a dictionary composed of numpy arrays, if key matches with row string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a dictionary composed of numpy arrays which are the vectors generated from the output of my word2vec model. The size of the dict is around 2000. Providing a sample of the data here:

```
my_dict = {'disease a': array([ 0.2520773 ,  0.433798],

      dtype=float32), 'disease b': array([0.12321666, 0.64195603],

      dtype=float32), 'disease c': array([0.38915345, 0.5541569], dtype=float32)}
```

I have a column in a csv which is in this form:

```
disease a, disease c

disease b

disease c, disease b

disease c
```

For each row in the csv I want to check if each element in a row is present in the dictionary key and if present I want to get the values for that dictionary key in the csv.

So, output should look like:

```
Disease                             Vectors

disease a, disease c         [[ 0.2520773 ,  0.433798],[0.38915345, 0.5541569]]

disease b                    [0.12321666, 0.64195603]

disease c, disease b         [[0.38915345, 0.5541569],[0.12321666, 0.64195603]]

disease c                    [0.38915345, 0.5541569]
```

Code updates:

```
symptoms_final=[]
with open("Documents/docs.csv", 'r') as csvfile:  
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    fields = next(csvreader)
    for row in csvreader:
        symptoms_final.append(row)
nsplitter = [el[0].split(',') for el in symptoms_final]
last_symptoms= [[s.strip() for s in inner] for inner in nsplitter]
last_symptoms = [i for i in last_symptoms if i]        
        
vectorz = []        
for vec in last_symptoms:
#    print(i)
    wwb = [my_dict.get(i.strip()) for i in vec]
    qz = vec, wwb
    vectorz.append(qz)
    
    
with open('io.csv', 'w') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
     writer.writerows(vectorz)
```

This outputs something like:
[array([ 0.473597,  0.224282,  0.510525, -0.6407305 ,  0.23232001],
dtype=float32)] for row in a csv that contains 1 element and hence for more than 1 element seems very unclean. Any idea on how to clean up the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you what you want. A little modification of your own solution:

```
rows=[]
with open("Documents/docs.csv", 'r') as csvfile:  
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    fields = next(csvreader)
    for row in csvreader: 
      rows.append([my_dict.get(i.strip()) for i in row])            
w = open('output.csv', 'w')
for row in rows:
    w.write("["+",".join(["["+",".join(map(str,x))+"]" for x in row])+"]\n")
```

UPDATE: if you want to replace missing keywords in dictionary with and array of `None`, replace this line:

```
      rows.append([my_dict.get(i.strip(), [None,None]) for i in row])
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting an error because some of the values in the 'rows' variable is of NoneType as no values were matched from the my_dict dictionary. The error is "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable". Any changes to code for solving this?

Comment: @Erich You can easily fix that. What do you wish to do with the missing keys? simply not including anything in the new file for them or putting a `None` maybe in their place?

Comment: None in their place so that I can track them

Comment: @Erich Please find my edit on the post to address your missing cases.

Comment: I have made some changes to the code. Can you please check if it's correct. Seems good to me. Just the output needs clean up. Posting updated code and output in question section

Comment: @Erich I do not see any edit on question. Did the posted answer not solve your issue? If not, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Just updating. With the code that I ran, it's automatically taking None for 0 occurrences. Just a minute while I update

Comment: Can you please check now.

Answer (score 1):

As another possibility:

```
rows=[]
with open("Documents/docs.csv", 'r') as csvfile:
  csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
  fields = next(csvreader)
  for row in csvreader:
    # Remove spaces (or search in dict will fail):
    rows.append([text.strip() for text in row])

# Mapping: from disease/key list, to vector/value list
values = map(
  lambda row: [my_dict.get(key) for key in row],
  rows
)

# Mapping: from numpy.array, to list (optional?)
# (done to match your desired output format)
vectors = map(
  lambda val: [[arr[0], arr[1]] for arr in val],
  values
)

for r,v in zip(rows, vectors):
  # Use str.join, to match your desired output format
  print(' '.join(r), v)
```